# how to show list text in XXXXXX format in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my demo I am showing list of `phone numbers`.I am able to show that.But I issue is I don't want to show whole number "10 digit" .I want to show only `2` digit number rest 'XXXXXXXX'.

can we show like that

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-field-fonus

```
export default function App() {
  const [state,setState] = useState(['9891234567','7856321234','8724329876'])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
{
  state.map((i)=>(<li>{i}</li>))
}

      </ul>
    </div>
  );
```

I want to show like that

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you might do:

```
state.map((i)=>(<li key={i}>{i.slice(0,2) + 'XXXXXXXX' }</li>))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will replace all characters but the first two with X for a string of any length.

`state.map(i => <li>{i.slice(0, 2)+'X'.repeat(i.length-2)}</li>);`

Answer (score 0):

I do a function to format the numbers, and after that, I let the original map. Here I made an example https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-vaughan-3o3fi

Answer (score 0):

If the shape of the string is going to be the same, you could use @Danko's mentioned solution else you could just make it dynamic if the string lengths might change

```js
{state.map(i => (<li key={i}>{i.slice(0,2) + 'X'.repeat(i.length - 2)}</li>))}
```